Is GARCH (and or it's variations) actually used in risk-modelling for expected-shortfall?
I understand there are limitations and practicality issues with GARCH, but does any company actually use it in their risk-management system when calculating their expected-shortfalls? Even as a basis with other components layered on, and extra estimation, tinkering etc?
If it is, is there actually any evidence of this with someone who's written a book/paper who's previously worked in a risk-management department at an financial institution? Every practitioner's guide I find is written by career professors.

Gooling "using GARCH for VaR" (note VaR rather than ES) finds dozens of articles. Do you see much literature on ES at all, irrespective of whether GARCH is used?

@DimitriVulis I see CVaR, which is the same thing. I find articles, but like I say, the ones I find are written by people in academia. The results seem reasonable, but like I said, I’m trying to see if GARCH is being used at some capacity, because I know sometimes academia can go off into the deep-end of theoretical and completely lose touch of reality, and what practitioners actually do.

What I’m envision (if it were used), would be that a risk-management team has 200 assets in their portfolio, they use a dimension reduction method (like PCA) to reduce the assets modelled, use some GARCH and  multivariate method to model their dependencies. And there would be some tweaking to correctly model things like intraday vs daily, weekend effects etc

Generally, folks who actually work in the industry - banks and other financial institutions - don't publish/disclose technical details of their calculations. As an example, let's take a look at Citi's 2023 10K : https://www.citigroup.com/rcs/citigpa/storage/public/10k20231231.pdf pages 115-116 . It describes only in very general terms how they have a covariance matrix based on historical time series  and run Monte Carlo. They don't say, for example, how many simulations they use for MC.  You'll have to hope that the folks in academia who publish articles talk to the ones in the industry.

The 480k x 480k covariance matrix is very impressive, but actually very sparse - most correlations aren't materially different from 0. But, does any bank already report conditional VaR / FRTB extended shortfall on their 10-K or equivalent, or are they still all in the process of adding that to production?

@DimitriVulis I read the pages you described and it does seem it does there is a very complicated model at play (480k x 480k). But is GARCH actually being used? Mainly, because I am currently working in a very young financial institution that does about 500m/year revenue and >1T flow. The issue is that there is zero risk-management plan and I am slowly trying to migrate them to more sophistication in their risk-modelling. I am slowly trying to build up a risk-framework with capital requirements, hedging costs, etc with using GARCH as a basis (any non-constant vol model basically)

@DimitriVulis As it stands, this company grew too quickly, so there is no-one within the company that even knows what a MC simulation is. And trying to tell the owner that we need to hire a senior risk-modeller on 250k+ salary will fail. Therefore, I am stuck with what I learned in my bachelors and masters, and am slowly trying to build-up a risk-model. But I am not sure if it's a waste of time going down this route, because in reality, GARCH is too complicated to be practical. For context, we have no derivatives on our books (only spot & FX), but trade every asset class.

@DimitriVulis The current risk-management is quite literally: if we didn't hedge X amount in the past would have we gone bankrupt? So when I start talking about correlated risk-exposure during crashes, volatility clusters, optimization etc my boss and the owner have no idea if I am talking out my ass, or I have lost my mind. They don't have technical degrees so they don't know if I a selling snake-oil when I explain the mathematics and stylized facts of the market. But if I can point to an article written by someone that worked at Citi, Merryl, Deustche etc, then they will have more belief.

Frankly, if I were in such a situation, I probably wouldn't reinvent the wheel in-house, but rather look at vendor solutions like (now MSCI's) RiskMetrics, QRM, or Bloomberg. Of course, the client would still need to understand what the vendor is doing, and ask if they want more done.

@DimitriVulis Thanks for the links. I will discuss with my boss. We a somewhat non-traditional in that we are an OTC brokerage that takes the opposite side of clients trades. So if a customer is long, we essentially have a synthetic short position. We do not get a say in specific the positions we take, although we can hedge with a 3rd-party if we don't want to internalize the exposure. Obviously with limited information, you're giving guess-work, but would you recommend finding a market-risk consultant? Or are they terrible value for money in general.

I'm always happy to spout my opinions, sorry that I'm digressing from your original question.  I'll just FX just as a concrete example that everyone knows. Suppose you have a small business selling spot foreign currency to, or buying spot from small end-users - too small for large liquidity providers to trade with. Because your costs are lower, you can offer attractive bid-ask spreads. Say, several customers buy some GBP from you, we can(?) presume because they need to pay their suppliers in the U.K. You plan is to buy some GBP from a big bank like C or GS at the end of the day. But...

(that's assuming your small business is large enough for big banks to trade with you - you may need  smaller liquidity provider). Or maybe you ait and home that some customer will sell you some EUR.  But before you execute your your planned hedge, you realize, in this order, that 1) your customers have been reading the Bloomberg terminal more diligently than you 2) some dude in a Guy Fox mask just mowed down a whole lot of prominent Labour politicians (just a hypothetical, not advocating this:) 3) the market thinks this is great news for the U.K. and the GBP... (cont)


covering your "synthetic short" GBP is going to be expensive, 5)  VaR, if you had one, didn't look so risky. What are some lessons that we can learn from this hypothetical scenario, besides VaR not being enough? You have to identify your market risks, articulate your risk appetite (how much intraday delta is too much for you, which may be lower at the times of day when you can't hedge), measure and monitor them (keep track of your intraday delta), and re-hedge a soon as you're uncomfortable, which may may be the middle of the night or weekend if your customers can trade with your computer..


before you start looking at better kinds of VaR, make sure your market risk management framework with just deltas and vegas and stress scenarios is comprehensive and robust, and any VaR will fit in fine. If you already have a framework, but no VaR, and want to add VaR to it, then yes, I think vendor VaR + your framework monitoring VaR exposure is good. If you don't even have limits monitoring for the deltas, then I think you should start with - articulating how much delta would be too much for your risk appetite, how you'd reduce it. Don't start with (any) VaR as the corner stone.

I found an example: Martin Auer. Hands-On Value-at-Risk and Expected Shortfall: A Practical Primer. Springer (2018). The blurb gives his affiliation as Raiffeisen Bank International, Vienna, Austria. (note: I condemn Raiffeisen for doing business in Russia.) His linkedin profile also mentions Bank of America. We can assume that whatever he describes is close to what some large and medium banks actually use. He writes (page 46):

Location of Local Vola Window The time series of returns exhibit varying vola
levels, also called heteroscedasticity. A vola rescaling operator does not leverage but actively tries to destroy this property. To do this, it must estimate the local volatility of the region a return resides in.


The textbook approach for this is to use so-called GARCH (short for, you guessed
it, generalized autoregressive conditional heteroscedasticity) models. Such models
are mathematically sound and widely used in literature. In fact, the original filtered historical VaR simulations rely on GARCH, which makes its application easy to defend. (Footnote: Just as nobody got ever fired for buying IBM, no vola model was ever rejected for relying on GARCH.) But GARCH models must be fit first—in our case, 2200 times or once for each risk factor, and repeatedly. This means an increased implementation effort and plenty of things that can go wrong. It also makes it difficult or impossible to precisely reenact model results for anyone who does not command a ready time series analysis kit. For these reasons, we propose to use a poor man’s version of a vola estimate, the plain standard deviation.


When using the standard deviation, it is tempting to stick with as many GARCH
conventions as possible to minimize any perception of deviation from an ingrained,
established method. Since GARCH is essentially a regression-based approach, it
relies on returns up to, but not including, the day for which a vola is estimated.
In that line, the standard deviation of those same, preceding returns could be used
for estimating the local vola of a return about to be rescaled. This is not necessary, however, as the standard deviation is simply not bound by regression limitations. In fact, if you were tasked to come up with a risk factor’s volatility for some January 15, you would most likely take the standard deviation of that month’s returns, never even considering to drop the return of the 15th itself from that estimate...

